# How to remove old kernel in 16.04

Tags: kernel, 16.04, removing

I am using Linux Ubuntu mate-desktop 4.4.0-24-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 8 19:27:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Just recently I am experiencing problems with updating and specifically with an older kernel - 4.4.0-22 (linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic).  It is marked for removal but not being removed.  I am not a Linux guru by any means!  I need help here to completely remove this older kernel.  Here is what I have copied from the terminal.

```
root@xxxxxxxxxx-desktop:/home/xxxxxxxxxx# apt-get autoremove -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 162 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 272391 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic (4.4.0-22.40) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-22-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-22-.generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-22-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-22-generic 
./boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-22-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-22-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-22-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-22-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-22-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_U8szG6/lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/modules.order: No such file or directorydepmod: WARNING: .
could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_U8szG6/lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/update-initramfs: 206: /usr/sbin/update-initramfs: cannot create /var/lib/initramfs-tools/4.4.0-22-generic: Directory nonexistent
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 2
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@xxxxxxxxxx-desktop:/home/xxxxxxxxxx#
```

Hope this is enough info to get started.

Comment: Same problem (remove old Kernel ).
This is solve problem [answer problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)

Comment: This is a "me to" comment, only in my case the old, non-existent, kernel is 4.4.0-31. It's gotten to the point where I can't install any packages, of any sort.

Answer (score 0):

The `linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic` package depends on `linux-image-4.4.0-22-generic` which is also the origin of the missing `/boot/System.map-4.4.0-22-generic` (this could be considered a bug). So as odd as it may sound you need to install the latter to then be able to remove both:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.4.0-22-generic
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-4.4.0-22-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic
```

They should have been (auto-)removed together the first time and I have no idea why that didn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most recommended way to remove unused kernels is the **Update manager**. From the *View* menu (of the **Update manager**'s main window) select *Linux kernels*. In the appearing window, select the kernel you want to uninstall. Then everything is done by the **Update manager**.